# Class number/ quadratic field/divisibility

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

If we take $n$ an even integer and greater than $5$, then $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{1 - 4k^n})$ are divisible by $n$, other than for $k = 13$ and $n = 8$. Why this is happened? If we take $n$ less than 5 (I mean for $n = 2$ or $n = 4$) what will happen?

Comment: Your first claim, how do you know?

Comment: @Will Jagy! I had some idea on quadratic fields. I believe the statement. I am not sure. If you can, you can disprove also.

Comment: @vmrfdu123456 As I've seen during my edit you have an idea about using LaTeX. Then why don't do this?

Comment: @Copycat Please explain the reason of this bounty. As far as I've seen the problem has an accepted answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $\alpha = \sqrt{1 - 4 k^n}$, and let $K = \mathbf{Q}(\sqrt{\alpha})$. Suppose that $k > 1$. I understand your question to be:  **why is the class number of $K$ divisible by $n$?**

The minimal polynomial of $\theta = \displaystyle{\frac{1 + \alpha}{2}}$ is
$$\theta^2 - \theta + k^n = 0.$$
Indeed, we even have $\mathbf{Z}[\theta]$ is the ring of integers of $K$.
Let $p$ be a prime dividing $k$. Then $p$ splits in $K$, as can be seen by factoring the polynomial above modulo $p$. Indeed, there is a unique such ideal which divides $\theta$, namely $\mathfrak{p} = (p,\theta)$. Equally, every prime dividing $\theta$ also divides $k$.
Since $\theta$ and $1 - \theta$ are co-prime, and since
$$\theta \overline{\theta} = \theta (1 - \theta) = k^n,$$
it follows that the exponent of $\mathfrak{p}$ in $\theta$ is $n$-times the exponent of $\mathfrak{p}$ in $k$. In particular,
there exists an ideal $\mathfrak{a}$ of norm $k$ such that
$\mathfrak{a}^n = (\theta)$.
Suppose that $\mathfrak{a}^m$ is principal. Then
$$k^m = N(\mathfrak{a}) = a^2 + ab + b^2 k^n = (a + b/2)^2 + b^2(k^n - 1/4) \ge k^n,$$
as long as $b \ne 0$. Yet if $b = 0$, then $(\theta^m) = \mathfrak{a}^{mn} = (a^n)$, and then $\theta = \pm a^n$ (the only units in $K$ are $\pm 1$), which is nonsense. Hence $k^m \ge k^n$, and thus $m \ge n$ (using the fact that $k > 1$), and thus the order of $\mathfrak{a}$ in the class group is exactly $n$. It follows that the class number is divisible by $n$ for any $n$.

Comment: J.Moose! your explanation is too good. But, my question is why the class number of k is not divisible by n,  in the cases of n = 2 and n = 4? Please explain.

Comment: @vmrdu, the class number *is* divisible by $n$ for all $n$ (I just proved it), and is thus so also for $n=2$, $n=4$, $n=1597$, and any other natural number.

Comment: @vrmdu, you have 24 hours to ask an coherent follow up question or accept this answer, otherwise it gets deleted.

Comment: Time is running out!

Comment: J.Moose! please click on http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/260516/class-number-quadratic-field-divisibility-2 and answer...

Comment: Dear Bullwinkle, In the 3rd last line, maybe $\theta = \pm a^{n/m}$? Regards,